# Show that if $y$ is a nontrivial solution of $y''+y=0$, then either $y(0)\neq 0$ or $y′(0)\neq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to solve every problem in [John M. Erdman's Exercises and Problems in Calculus](http://web.pdx.edu/%7Eerdman/CALCULUS/CALCULUS_pdf.pdf). I'm at 7.3, [problem 2, c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxPR3.jpg).

(2)(c) Show that if $y$ is a nontrivial solution of $y''+y=0$, then either $y(0)\neq 0$ or $y′(0)\neq 0$

**Proof**

Let $y$ be a nontrivial solution of $y''+y=0$ such that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$. Since the general solution for our equation is $y(t) = C_1\cos t + C_2\sin t$ for some constants $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $y'(t) = -C_1\sin t + C_2 \cos t$. For $t=0$ we get

$0 =  y(0) = C_1\cos 0 + C_2\sin 0 = C_1$

$0 =  y'(0) = -C_1\sin 0 + C_2\cos 0 = C_2$

Since $C_1=0$  and $C_2=0$, we have that $y(t) = 0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ which implies that $y$ is trivial. $\blacksquare$

I think I'm missing the point of the problem since (d) assumes that I didn't solve the equation and solving 2nd order linear homogeneous differential equations is not part of the theory required for this chapter. Is there another way to prove the statement without solving the equation?

Comment: You seem to have misread/miscopied the question.  "... then either $y(0) \neq 0$ or $y'(0) \neq 0$."  Quoted from your link.

Comment: Do you mean $y(0) \ne 0$ or $y'(0) \ne 0$, rather than $=$?

Comment: Yes. I changed it.

Comment: What do you know about the space of solutions of a linear DE? Do you know what a Cauchy problem is?

Comment: Not sure about the first question, but I do know what a Cauchy problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having inspected the cited problem and it's surroundings, I note that part (b) of problem (2) asks us to show that
$(y')^2 + y^2$ is constant; this is seen to be an easy consequence of

$y'' + y = 0 \tag 1$

as follows: we have

$((y')^2 + y^2)' = 2y'y'' + 2yy' = -2yy' + 2yy' = 0, \tag 2$

using (1).  Now with

$y(0) = y'(0) = 0, \tag 3$

we have

$(y')^2 + y^2 = (y'(0))^2 + y^2(0) = 0 \tag 4$

everywhere; thus

$y' = y = 0, \tag 5$

that is, $y$ is the trivial solution to (1).  Then if $y$ is not trivial, (3) cannot bind and at least one of $y(0)$, $y'(0)$ does not vanish.  Note that we may in fact have

$y(0) \ne 0 \ne y'(0). \tag 6$

Answer (score 0):

If $y+y''=0$, then $yy'+y'y''=0$
so $(y^2)'+((y')^2)' =0$
so $y^2+(y')^2=c$
for some real $c$.

Since $y$ is non-trivial, $y(x) \ne 0$ for some $x$,
so $c \ne 0$.

Therefore if
 $y(x)=0$
then $(y'(x))^2 = c \ne 0$
and if
 $y'(x)=0$
then $(y(x))^2 = c \ne 0$.